# selection/active class for show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

So I have this thing where I need one div to be shown at any one time depending on the button clicked. I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sXqnD/15/) great fiddle which is almost perfect *except* for the fact that it doesn't show when one link is selected. I'd like to have it so that the link that's selected can have a sort of active class or look different from the other links. Is that possible? I've been looking through questions and I can't really find an answer for this.

If anyone's interested, I'm using it [for this](http://graftonway.tumblr.com/more) (but the code is really messed up, sorry). (I'd also like to change the filter buttons on the top row to reset and filter all the images, but am aware that's a different question. Still any help would be appreciated!)

html

```
<div id="linkwrapper">
    <a id="link1" href="#">link1</a><br/>
    <a id="link2" href="#">link2</a><br/>
    <a id="link3" href="#">link3</a>
</div>

<div id="infocontent">
    <div id="link1content">Information about 1.</div>
    <div id="link2content">Information about 2.</div>
    <div id="link3content">Information about 3.</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#infocontent").hide();
    $("#infocontent div").hide();


    $('#linkwrapper a[id]').click(function(){

        var vsubmen = this.id +"content";  

        if( $("#infocontent").is(":visible") == false ) {
            $("#" + vsubmen).show('fast',function() {
                $("#infocontent").slideDown();
            });
        } else if ( $("#" + vsubmen).is(":visible") == false ) {
            $("#infocontent").slideUp('slow',function(){
                $("#infocontent div").hide();
                $("#" + vsubmen).show();
                $("#infocontent").slideDown('slow');    
            });
        } else {
            $("#infocontent").slideUp('slow',function(){
                $("#infocontent div").hide();
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify that fiddle like this:

```
$('a[id^=link]').click(function(){
    $('a[id^=link]').removeClass('meactive');
    $(this).addClass('meactive');

    $('#infocontent>div').slideUp();

    var tmp = this.id;
    $('#'+tmp+'content').slideDown();
}); //end a.click
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9k6v8gb/)</kbd>

---

Notes:

(1) `$('a[id^=link]')` -- grabs all `a` elements with a ID that **starts with** `link`

(2) `$('#' +tmp+ 'content')` -- builds selectors like: `$('#link3content`)`

Comment: If this answer solves your question, then please close the question by marking it as the correct answer (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer). *Best wishes for your project.*